# Difference in find command syntax

Tags: linux, shell, find

Looking at the find command I am curious what the difference is between the two:

```
find -type f
```

and

```
find ${1} -type f
```

They both seem to perform the same function so what is the `${1}` for?

Comment: what is the reason to use `${1}` in `find`? In arbitrary case `${1}` gives you nothing

Comment: BSD Linux requires the directory you want to find files in. GNU Linux assumes no current dir means you want to find in the current working directory (plus subdirs)

Answer (score 2):

This `${1}` has nothing to do with the find, it is a shell parameter.

If the second find command runs inside a shell script, for example is your `test.sh` is like:

```
#!/bin/bash
find ${1} -type f
```

Then, if you call this `test.sh` with

```
./test.sh cica
```

Then the `cica` will be substituted by the shell into the `find` command line. The `find` command will see a

```
find cica -type f
```

..and so will it run (thus, it will look for files in the `cica` directory and not in the current directory).

P.s. Once in our lifes we all should read the manual of `bash`, `ls`, `cp` and `strace`.

Comment: and `find`, and `sed`, and `grep`, and...

Comment: @DopeGhoti Right, I didn't want to overload him on the spot, but I agree :-)

Answer (score 2):

As @DopeGhoti mentioned, ${1} (or $1) is the first argument to a script or function.

I suspect that the code you're questioning is a part of a function that looks something like this:

```
#/bin/bash
function show {
    find ${1} -type f -print
}
show        #...find with current directory as starting point...
show mydir  #...find using `mydir` as starting point...
```

That is, if no argument is present when the function is called, `${1}` is empty and `find -type f...` is run.

Answer (score 1):

`${1}` (or `$1`) is the first argument to a script or function.  The command you call out in your question is likely in a script.  For a very basic example:

```
#!/bin/bash
find "${1}" -type f
```

If that file were saved as an executable `seek.sh`, and you ran the command `./seek.sh /home`, the command that would be executed is `find "/home" -type f`.